# Ruby. How to know which class instance method is defined?

Tags: ruby, class, metaprogramming, instance, method-missing

I want to know which class method_missing is defined.
It is defined in Object.

How can I figure out which class along the hierarchy overrides it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`UnboundMethod#owner`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/UnboundMethod.html#method-i-owner) method to check where the method is implemented:

```
class A
  def method_missing(*args)
    # do something
  end
end
method = A.instance_method(:method_missing)
method.owner
# => A
```

Note: If the method is implemented in module (which is later mixed into the class hierarchy somewhere), `owner` will return this module.

Comment: Good answer. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you can stop with `method`, which returns `#<UnboundMethod: A#method_missing>` (assuming it's just for debugging and you don't need the class returned in the code itself).

Comment: No, `A.method(:method_missing)` returns `Method` instance representing `BasicObject#method_missing`, instead of `A#method_missing`. It's because `A#method_missing` is implemented as instance method, not class method.

Comment: I was referring to the value of your variable `method`, which is displayed as `#<UnboundMethod: A#method_missing>`, showing the owner, `A`. Similarly, for `class B<A; end; class C<B; end`,  `C.instance_method(:method_missing) => #<UnboundMethod: C(A)#method_missing>`, again showing `A` as the owner. Correct?

Comment: Yes, and it's exactly what OP wanted.

Comment: My only point was that you don't have to add `.owner` to see who the owner is.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Though calling `owner` makes it clear, so I don't think my answer need modification.

Comment: @MarekLipka Yes, it helps. This is what I want.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Both comments help. Thank you, too.